# `Kernel panic - not synicing: No init found` while installing any version of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, kernel

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.10 however I've got a problem:

The live environment works fine, and the installation too. However when I try to boot the computer after installation it displays the purple screen, and nothing else. When I reboot the computer I get the following error:

```
[ 0.958197] Kernel panic - not synicing: No init found. Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guideance.
```

The things I tried to solve it:

- Boot from recovery mode: The same error appears.
- Different ways of partitioning (also letting the installer figure out what to do): has no effect
- Installing Ubuntu 12.04: Again same problem as 13.10
- Doing a memtest: memory is okay.
- Doing an fsck: everything is clean.

I have both used 12.04 and 13.04 before on that computer and it worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could install 13.04, then do an upgrade from there.

Answer (score 1):

I inserted an extra hard drive, and I did not wire them properly (HDD in SATA3_0 and SSD in SATA3_1). Despite my computer working fine normally, this wiring caused Ubuntu to not being able to reinstall.

Rewiring the hard drives solved the issue.